# blurryness in skybox?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, skybox

ive made a skybox with the following class and the image comes out blurry in some parts of the sky and the grass, im trying to figure out how to fix it, thank you for your time.
[image: image from emulator]

```
public class SkyBox {
private static final String TAG = "skybox";
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;  // Vertex Buffer
private FloatBuffer texBuffer;     // Texture Coords Buffer

private int numFaces = 6;
private int[] imageFileIDs = {  // Image file IDs
  R.drawable.skybox,
  R.drawable.skybox1,
  R.drawable.skybox2,
  R.drawable.skybox3,
  R.drawable.skybox4,
  R.drawable.skybox5
};
private int[] textureIDs = new int[numFaces];
private Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[numFaces];
private float cubeHalfSize = 2f;

// Constructor - Set up the vertex buffer
public SkyBox(Context context) {
  // Allocate vertex buffer. An float has 4 bytes
  ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12 * 4 * numFaces);
  vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

  // Read images. Find the aspect ratio and adjust the vertices accordingly.
  for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
     bitmap[face] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
           context.getResources().openRawResource(imageFileIDs[face]));
     int imgWidth = bitmap[face].getWidth();
     int imgHeight = bitmap[face].getHeight();
     float faceWidth = 2.0f;
     float faceHeight = 2.0f;
     // Adjust for aspect ratio

        faceHeight = faceHeight * imgHeight / imgWidth; 

        faceWidth = faceWidth * imgWidth / imgHeight;

     float faceLeft = -faceWidth*20;
     float faceRight = -faceLeft;
     float faceTop = faceHeight*20;
     float faceBottom = -faceTop;

     // Define the vertices for this face
     float[] vertices = {
        faceLeft,  faceBottom, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
        faceRight, faceBottom, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
        faceLeft,  faceTop,    0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
        faceRight, faceTop,    0.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
     };
     vertexBuffer.put(vertices);  // Populate
  }
  vertexBuffer.position(0);    // Rewind

  // Allocate texture buffer. An float has 4 bytes. Repeat for 6 faces.
  float[] texCoords = {
     0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
     1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
     0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
     1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
  };
  ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4 * numFaces);
  tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
  for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
     texBuffer.put(texCoords);
  }
  texBuffer.position(0);   // Rewind
 }

 // Render the shape
 public void draw(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer);

  // front
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  // left
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[1]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  // back
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[2]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  // right
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[3]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  // top
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[4]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  // bottom
  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[5]);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 }

 // Load images into 6 GL textures
 public void loadTexture(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glGenTextures(6, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array for 6 IDs

  Log.d(TAG, "gen number = " + textureIDs[0]);
  // Generate OpenGL texture images
  for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
      Log.d(TAG, "gen number " + face + " = " + textureIDs[face]);
     gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[face]);
     gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
     gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

     // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
     GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap[face], 0);
     bitmap[face].recycle();
  }
  }
}
```